# "Leaking" Thread Handles

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0, threadpool

I have a WCF application hosted in IIS (written in `C#/.Net 4`).  Over time, the Handle Count of the process increases in a more or less linear fashion (increasing as high as 30,000 before the process recycles).  According to SysInternals Process Explorer, the bulk of the handles that the process has are of type `Thread`.  However, according to Performance Monitor, the number of threads is remaining more or less constant (around 40).

Clearly, I am doing something wrong and am leaking `Thread Handles`.  However, I'm unclear exactly what a `Thread Handle` is in this context.  I would have assumed that it is a handle to a thread, but since the number of threads is remaining consistent, I don't see how the handle count is ever increasing.  And, I can't think of any way to keep a handle to a thread, while the thread itself goes away.  Furthermore, I am not explicitely creating new threads (I am using the `ThreadPool` in places).

Clearly, I am missing something.  But what?

Comment: Do you have the WCF service as SingleInstance, PerCall or Session? Are you using a IoC container there?

Comment: Are you managing the threads by yourself or are you using the thread pool? Which kind of threads use your application (are we talking about the threads that IIS does -> limited by the IIS itself, or your own threads)?

Comment: The WCF Service is Single instance and Multiple concurrency.  No IOC Container.

Comment: I do spawn a couple of threads (I am certain that this is happening only once), and am using a couple of Timers (again, confident that I am not creating them many times).  The bulk of my thread operations are done using the Thread Pool.

Answer (score 1):

One can have handles to terminated threads. So the threads get created, terminate, but the handle remains.

Start Process Monitor (procmon.exe) and set it to listen to "Process and Thread Activity" (disable files, registry and network). Determine, who is creating threads by double-clicking thread create events and looking at the stack.

That should answer the question who is creating the threads. He is responsible for closing the handles.

Answer (score 0):

[According documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746.aspx):

> When a new thread is created by the [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) or [`CreateRemoteThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437.aspx) function, a handle to the thread is returned.

So if you have a so much handles, your application produces the new Threads constantly. From other side, near constant number of threads in the Performance Monitor says that Threads are created in place of recycled ones.

[ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.ThreadPool.aspx) class documentation:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the thread pool **creates and destroys worker threads in order to optimize throughput**, which is defined as the number of tasks that complete per unit of time. Too few threads might not make optimal use of available resources, whereas too many threads could increase resource contention.

So I think your application behaviour is because of the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen Thank you